# Concurrent AWS Lambdas runs more than once

Tags: c#, concurrency, aws-lambda, serverless

In my serverless environment in AWS, I have a LambdaA that is triggered once every minute.
The Lambda starts 50 concurrent Lambdas called "LambdaB" using the code below:

```
var listOfTasks = new List<Task<bool>>();
foreach(var item in listWith50Items)
{
    listOfTasks.Add(InvokeLambda(item, "LambdaB"));
}
return await Task.WhenAll<bool>(listOfTasks);
```

The problem is that sometimes lambdas are triggered more than once every minute? How can I trigger an Invoke for each item **exactly** once every minute, not more, not less... the code above does not seem to fix that..

Comment: How is the `LambdaA` invoked once every minute? Are you using a `Timer`?

Answer (score 1):

A different approach, You can use CloudWatch Schedule Expressions, as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

The simplest way is to use a serverless framework:
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/

```
functions:
  lambdaA:
    handler: lambdaA
    events:
      - schedule: cron(*/1 * * * *)
```

This cron means at every min `*/1 * * * *`

Comment: thanks for that idea, didnt know about that feature.